# multi-tenant and use of ruby delegate vs NoSQL for tenant context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant app (rails backend) and I need to mix a tenant-agnostic pre-populated list of items with tenant specific attributes.

Was wondering if I anyone has used delegate to get this done and had ok performance vs. venturing out of Postgres into MongoDB

example models:

```
Class EquipmentList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :category_id

  has_one :tenant_equipment_list

  delegate :alt_name, to: tenant_equipment_list

end

Class TenantEquipmentList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :alt_name, :group, :sku, :est_price, :equipment_list_id

  belongs_to :equipment_list

  default_scope { where(tenant_id: Tenant.current_id) }
end
```

Comment: Update: Been doing this in a low traffic site and haven't seen any issues to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run this successfully on a low traffic site.  The rails back end handles this pretty well in outputting to json.

Realized its better to use the tenant version as the foreign key and delegate master attributes to tenant.  Looks something like this:

```
Class EquipmentList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :category_id

  has_one :tenant_equipment_list



end

Class TenantEquipmentList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :alt_name, :group, :sku, :est_price, :equipment_list_id

  belongs_to :equipment_list

  delegate :name, to: tenant_equipment_list #prefix: true if you want

  default_scope { where(tenant_id: Tenant.current_id) }
end
```